# How to generate an executable form a matlab gui that doesn't require Matlab Compiler Runtime (MCR) on the machine

Tags: matlab-guide, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

How to generate an executable from a matlab gui that( The exe file) doesn't require Matlab Compiler Runtime (MCR) on the machine.
When I include Matlab runtime within the package, the size becomes too big.

Comment: Don't package the MCR with your application.  Have the client download and install it.

Comment: Yes I know that this option exists, but my question is, how can I make an executable that doesn't require the MCR to be installed on the computer.
My professor talked about creating a runtime using java, but I still don't understand how i'm going to do that, or what that exactly means...

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can come is to generate C/C++ code using [Matlab Coder](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/index.html) and build it as a standalone C/C++ executable,  but Matlab-Coder has many quirks and doesn't support the full set of Matlab functionality. Expect some rough waters if you head that way.

Using matlab *Compiler* - I'm afraid it just can't be done.

Comment: The Matlab code in question contains plotting functions which are not supported by Matlab Coder.
Is there a way to combine another tool/method with Matlab Coder so that Matlab Coder  handles the part on the code it supports, while the other "tool" handles the rest of the code, and at the end combine the results? @Ofek

Comment: Yes, but that tool would be matlab compiler. You can't generate such an executable without depending on the MCR.